# Can I get Windows 10 back that has gone while I am rebooting?

Tags: dual-boot, reboot

While I was dual booting with the USB I got structed with screen containing only "-"   blinking  on the screen. I have nearly waited for 30 min. It did not work. I turned on the PC again my Windows 10 was degraded to Windows XP, how it's possible?  But the Windows XP does not contain anything, totally blank  but the data is present. I can't access the Windows XP also as it is only blank again. I tried to boot the system with pendrive it has worked and I gone through the process after the process i.e. the booting is completed and I successfully installed Ubuntu but after restarting this line is displaying

> To reboot the device press any key or insert a boot device to boot

The main thing while I am booting Ubuntu is  the other space in my disk is filled with Windows 10 and XP while partitioning but while reacting I can't get both of them.

I can't get the OS to run. Can you help me in this regard and what are the steps to take and to get the Windows 10 again?

Comment: Boot-Repair will not fix most Windows issues, you need a Windows repair disk for that. But report can show lots of details, so we can see issues. Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have lost the boot entries after Ubuntu was installed. If you still got a bootable Linux USB stick, run a rescue image (or whatever's called command line environment), run

```
$ efibootmgr -v
```

(if I'm right, Ubuntu is booting successfully?)
Check if there's any Microsoft OS entry. If not, create one according to efibootmgr man page, and look for your XP and 10 efi file paths on your ESP (EFI System Partition it's called on Windows) to be linked while creating entries. After that, read somewhere about adding Microsoft OS entries to your GRUB loader.

Comment: If install has both XP & Windows 10, then it has to be the old BIOS/MBR configuration, not newer UEFI/gpt.

Comment: @oldfred Then I made a big mistake! Otherwise, the OP must be new to the Linux world, but somehow he managed to install XP on a GPT HDD with hax tools or whatever